# APPIUM:Change app language

Tags: appium

Iam automating an android app which is developed in few different langugages. I would like to know whether can we change the app language with desiredcapabilities?i passed the below capabilities. But it dint work.

```
obj.setCapability(“LOCALE”, “FR”);
obj.setCapability(“LANGUAGE”,“fr”);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always check [official docs](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps.md)

`obj.setCapability(“locale”, “ fr_CA”);
obj.setCapability(“language”,“fr”);`

**Both Sim/Emu-only** If it works on random real device, its more like a luck.

Language change available only on API levels 22 and below